# pandas apply first attempt on threading

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, pandas

I have a sample df of 1000 rows, that I read from excel, which looks like that:

```
    exFcode
0   38907030
1   47036870
2   54060696
3   38907039
4   100811680
(...)
```

I need to assign number of articles for each code. To do this I connect to an API taking each code (this API only allows 1 code per request) and return value in the second column of the df. Currently I do it this way:

```
def getArticles(code):
    r = requests.get(API_link % code).content
    jsonized = json.loads(r.decode("utf-8"))
    try:
        num_articles = jsonized["TotalRecords"]
    except:
        return 'not found'
    return num_articles

df['articles'] = df["exFcode"].apply(lambda row: getArticles(row))
```

It does the job but it's slow, performs each operation one by one. For 1000 codes it takes around 10 minutes. Very often I have to deal with files of 50k and more...

I was thinking how to do it more efficiently. I thought I could divide the df into 2 parts and then perform each part in separate thread. It's my first attempt of applying threading into my programs... So I have created two additional functions wrapper and main.

```
def wrapper(df):
    df['articles'] = df["exFcode"].apply(lambda row: getArticles(row))
    return df

def main(df):
    #separate df to two even halves
    half = int(len(df))
    df1 = df.iloc[:half]
    df2 = df.iloc[half:]
    t1 = Thread(target=wrapper, args=(df1,))
    t2 = Thread(target=wrapper, args=(df2,))
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
    print('completed')
```

However when I execute the function `main(df)` nothing happens. Am I completely misunderstanding the concept of threading? Any other idea how to make it more efficient?

Answer (score 1):

you print "complete" when the threads have started. But you're missing the `join` part to wait for them to complete.

```
t1.start()
t2.start()
print('threads started')
t1.join()
t2.join()
print('really completed')
```

Comment: Good point! Thanks. However I received several exceptions related to requests package. This must be a limitation of the API though...